# Dealing with Subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Just having a little trouble understanding how subspaces work. I know that to be a subspace it has to hold for vector addition and scalar multiplication, which I assume is equivalent to

$u+v = v+u$ and
$ku = (ku$1, $ku$2)

But how does that work for showing something like $U = [x,y,z | 3x + y - 2z = 0]$ as a subspace (let's assume for $R^3$ for now). How do you differentiate between the subspace equaling $0$ or say equaling $3$ and use it in the axioms for vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Also, let's say we had $U$ as a subspace of $R^4$ spanned by a set $V = [(3, -2, 0, 1), (1, -2, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3)]$ (completely random numbers just to show example) and we want to show that $V$ is a basis of $U$, would we still calculate linear independence and the span using just $V$ or?

I know that every spanning set for a subspace is either a basis for that subspace or has a basis as a subset, but not sure what to do to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subspace (say $U$) of a Vector Space automatically inherits its operations and the same field, additionally (you missed this) the operation must be closed in $U$, i.e, for any $x,y \in U, \alpha x + \beta y \in U ~ \forall ~ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb F$

That being said, if you want to figure out whether a given list of vectors is a basis of a (sub)space, you just need to check the following - whether they span the entire space & whether they are linearly independent.

As for your example, suppose $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are solutions to the equation $3x+y-2z=0$. Pick arbitrary field elements $\alpha,\beta$ and note that $3\alpha x_1+\alpha y_1-2  \alpha z_1+ 3 \beta x_2+\beta y_2 - \beta z_2=0$ or $3(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2)+(\alpha y_1+\beta y_2)-2(\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)=0$ which implies $(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2,  \alpha y_1+\beta y_2,\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)$ is a solution of the equation as well, showing that $U$ is "closed" under the operation. Hence it is a sub space of $\{ (x,y,z) : x,y,z \in \mathbb R \}$ or $\mathbb R^3$.

Note : This is a homogenous equation in three variables.

Comment: Ah ok. So you have to formulate potential solutions, so for instance, if it was $xy + z = 0$ then you could use (x1y1 + x2y2)+ (z1 + z2) = $0$ and show that it does not work with the solutions to (x1, y1, z1) + (x2, y2, z2).

Comment: If you want to show that a space of solutions isn't a subspace then yes.